# Javascript function not being called successfully

Tags: javascript, function

The idea for now is to just display "hello world!" to check if the function is being called properly by the button. I've tried to copy-paste from previous code that worked, checked the parentheses, brackets, anything that could disrupt the function call.
While nothing after the "hello world!" is necessary to answer the question, I'd greatly appreciate it if you gave suggestions for the rest of the code below. The idea there is to take user input, and give different results based on string length.

```js
function persona() {
  document.write("hello world!");
  var name, inputstr, sum = 0;
  name = document.getElementById("input").value;
  inputstr = name.length;
  while (inputstr / 10 >= 1) {
    if (inputstr = 11 || inputstr = 22) {
      break;
    }
    sum += inputstr % 10;
    inputstr = Math.floor(inputstr / 10);
    if (inputstr = 11 || inputstr = 22) {
      break;
    }
  }
  switch (inputstr) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 3:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 4:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 5:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 6:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 7:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 8:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 9:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 11:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 22:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a89b28;
  color: #f0f1f6;
  font-family: impact;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Number Personality Calculator</title>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Input your name, and predict your personality type" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="JavaScript, JS, numerology, personality" />
  <meta name="author" content="[REDACTED], 18/02/2018" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>PERSONALITY TYPE CHECKER</h1>
  <p id="results">""</p>
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Juan Dela Cruz"><br>
  <button onclick="persona()">Get your personality</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `document.write` after the page has been parsed (or maybe at all). `dw` clears the page and creates a new document.

Comment: You also shouldn't use attributes to assign event handlers. Use `element.addEventListener`.

Comment: If you want to check if a function is working, I'd suggest using `alert()` instead

Comment: Instead of document.write, you want to select the results element and change its `innerHTML` attribute. You can do this like: `let resultsElement = document.getElementById("results"); resultsElement.innerHTML = "Hello World.";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to fix the error with your code its because you are using assignment operators in your if statements instead of comparison operators.

Change `inputstr = x` to `inputstr == x`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Number Personality Calculator</title>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Input your name, and predict your personality type" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="JavaScript, JS, numerology, personality" />
  <meta name="author" content="[REDACTED], 18/02/2018" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #a89b28;
      color: #f0f1f6;
      font-family: impact;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>PERSONALITY TYPE CHECKER</h1>
  <p id="results">""</p>
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Juan Dela Cruz"></br>
  <button onclick="persona()">Get your personality</button>
  <script>
    function persona() {
      document.write("hello world!");
      var name, inputstr, sum = 0;
      name = document.getElementById("input").value;
      inputstr = name.length;
      while (inputstr / 10 >= 1) {
        if (inputstr == 11 || inputstr == 22) {
          break;
        }
        sum += inputstr % 10;
        inputstr = Math.floor(inputstr / 10);
        if (inputstr == 11 || inputstr == 22) {
          break;
        }
      }
      switch (inputstr) {
        case 1:
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
          break;;
        case 2:
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
          break;;
        case 3:
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
          break;;
        case 4:
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
          break;;
        case 5:
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
          break;;
        case 6:
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
          break;;
        case 7:
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
          break;;
        case 8:
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
          break;;
        case 9:
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
          break;;
        case 11:
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
          break;;
        case 22:
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
          break;;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your HTML markup looks like that for me, to **console.log** or **alert()** the "Hello World" has proven to be a saver way of testing whether a function is working.

Maybe **try that just in case** the function gets actually called but there is another thing not working with the rest of the code...

Answer (score 0):

On lines 8 and 14 (in my snippet), you had single equals inside an if statement. That's a very simple mistake that could throw your whole code off.

Debugging is a very valuable tool. Always when debugging, use `alert()` or `console.log()` not `document.write()`. Personally, the way I debug is by slowly removing the lines one by one seeing which one causes the error. That way is slow and tedious, but foolproof. I caught your error in no time.

`=` is meant to assign a value to a variable. `==` is meant to compare 2 values. If you try to use `=` inside an if statement, it will completely break your code (you shouldn't be assigning anything inside an if statement. Only comparing).

```js
function persona() {
  alert("hello world!");
  var name, inputstr, sum = 0;
  name = document.getElementById("input").value;
  inputstr = name.length;
  while (inputstr / 10 >= 1) {
    //You had single equals below. Should be double
    if (inputstr == 11 || inputstr == 22) {
      break;
    }
    sum += inputstr % 10;
    inputstr = Math.floor(inputstr / 10);
    //You had single equals below. Should be double
    if (inputstr == 11 || inputstr == 22) {
      break;
    }
  }
  switch (inputstr) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 3:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 4:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 5:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 6:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 7:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 8:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 9:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 11:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
    case 22:
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "...";
      break;;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a89b28;
  color: #f0f1f6;
  font-family: impact;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Number Personality Calculator</title>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Input your name, and predict your personality type" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="JavaScript, JS, numerology, personality" />
  <meta name="author" content="[REDACTED], 18/02/2018" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>PERSONALITY TYPE CHECKER</h1>
  <p id="results">""</p>
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Juan Dela Cruz"><br>
  <button onclick="persona()">Get your personality</button>
</body>

</html>
```